# python help! invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

hi currently doing a code where the programe recalls two files one with positions of words the other words the following code combines them however when i change my code to be imported from a file i get the following error (if compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)]==uncompressed: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['1',")

here is my code aswell:

```
uncompressed = 0

file1 = open ("NonDupT2.txt" , "r")
compressed_sentence=file1.read()
file1.close()

file1 = open ("PositionT2.txt" , "r")
compressed_Positionsonly=file1.read()
file1.close()

compressed_Positions= compressed_Positionsonly.split()

print(str(compressed_Positions))

for i in compressed_Positions:
    if compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)]==uncompressed:    
        print(compressed_sentence[(int(i))])
        uncompressed = compressed_sentence[(int(i))]

    else:
        print(compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)])
        uncompressed=compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)]

    print(str(int(i)))
```

however it work  when the variables are detemined by the program

```
uncompressed = 0

compressed_sentence = ['hello' , 'hello' , 'why' , 'hello' , 'lmao']
compressed_Positions = ['1' , '1' , '2' , '1' , '3']

print(str(compressed_Positions))

for i in compressed_Positions:

    if compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)]==uncompressed:    
        print(compressed_sentence[(int(i))])
        uncompressed = compressed_sentence[(int(i))]

    else:
        print(compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)])
        uncompressed=compressed_sentence[(int(i)-1)]

    print(str(int(i)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the compressed_Positions are read wrongly. The file reads the contents as one string. That string is the entire contents of the text file.

The split operator makes a list of strings. The first element of that list is everything from the file until the first space and that appears to be

```
'[1,'
```

And that is what is interpreted by int() and that does not work. I think that your PositionT2.txt contains:

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

It works if it contained:

```
1 1 2 1 3
```

To make the program work the same as the example with the explicit definition, you need a split operator for compressed_sentences as well and your NonDupT2.txt file must contain

```
hello hello why hello lmao
```

Instead of spaces, you can also use line breaks as separators in your text file.

Good luck,
Joost